# Change how the List Component works in ActoinSciprt 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am trying to make a list component that will display items, everything works, but it adds the items not the way I want it to!

Let's say I send a command that first adds the line "User1" and then the line "User2". This is how it displays the items:

> - *User1*
> - *User2*

While I wanted it "upside down", so it should've been looked like this:

> - *User2*
> - *User1*

Likewise, if I add a "User3", it should be looking like this:

> - *User3*
> - *User2*
> - *User1*

Can I do this somehow? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`addItem()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/controls/SelectableList.html#addItem()) method of the [`SelectableList`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/controls/SelectableList.html) class (the super class of the [`List`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/controls/List.html) class) *appends* the item to the end of the list.

The *index* value for the row layout starts at `0` (i.e. the first item has an index value of `0`.) Now that every time you want to insert the item to the beginning of the list, you need to utilize the method of [`addItemAt()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/controls/SelectableList.html#addItemAt()) with an index value of `0`:

```
import fl.controls.List;
var lst:List = new List();

lst.addItemAt({label:"One",   data:1}, 0);
lst.addItemAt({label:"Two",   data:2}, 0);
lst.addItemAt({label:"Three", data:3}, 0);

addChild(lst);
```

Comment: Can I do the same thing with appendText?

Comment: @ProgramKiddo There is nothing as the `appendText` in the class hierarchy of the `List` component! BTW, you're welcome, and if you've found the answer useful, please consider [accepting it as an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) :)

Comment: Not talking about the list one ;) I'm using the appendText for a textarea component

Comment: @ProgramKiddo Actually, there is no dedicated method to cause the same behavior on the `TextArea` component. However, you can always use the `txtArea.text = "YourText" + txtArea.text;` it's pretty much intuitive and _prepends_ your string to the start of the text :)

Comment: I thought it would mess things up, but it actually works lol :O thank you again!